# NoSuchMethodError when setting a custom progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, nosuchmethoderror

I am using a custom progress bar and it works on my physical phone just fine. However, I am created a tablet layout of my app and tried it on an emulator and it gives me this error message - NoSuchMethodError
Here is the piece of code where I am setting my custom progress bar:
line 34 is where I am setting the interterminateDrawable. 
The minimum sdks version is 14

```
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));
```

Here is the log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage.LoginActivity.getDrawable
        at koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `getDrawable()` convenience method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable%28int%29) on `Context` was added in API Level 21. Your tablet may be running an older version.

> The minimum sdks version is 14

The build tools should have complained about your use of `getDrawable()` here. Either raise your `minSdkVersion` to 21, or use something else, such as the `getDrawable()` method on `Resources` (and you can get a `Resources` by calling `getResources()` on your activity).

Comment: Thanks! That worked!
However, Android Studio says that getDrawable(ing) is deprecated. I did a little search and found that I would use getDrawable(ing, theme) instead. I did that: mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress,getTheme()));
However, the same error appeared... any idea why ? :)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev: Because [the two-parameter `getDrawable()` method on `Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme%29) is also new to API Level 21. Your choices are to use the deprecated one all the time, or use it for older devices and use the two-parameter one for devices running API Level 21 or higher. You can use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to determine what API level the device is that you are running on.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        seekBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(main_activity, R.color.your_color)));
    }
    else
    {
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(main_activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
```